# command line parameter to qt binary in linux

Tags: qt, command, line, command-line-arguments

I am on an embedded device. I am running several qt application from shell.
I alway have to pass the '-platform linuxfb' parameter.

- Is there a setting so it appends automatic or let the running env
  knows when a qt app is launched, so I don't have always to type it.

  or
- Is there a compile settings that would always have the
  -platform linuxfb

Answer (score 1):

I guess I found it.

QT_QPA_PLATFORM environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can also build your Qt such that it uses the `linuxfb` QPA by default.

`configure -qpa linuxfb ...`